# How to select an employee from a dataframe with a desired country in pandas?

Tags: python

I have done a python code to select an employee from a dataframe according to a desired country. Code is given below :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

your_origin_country = 'China'

employee_data = df
employee_data

selected_employee = employee_data[employee_data['origin_country'] == your_origin_country].iloc[0]
```

My dataframe is given below :

```
| first_name | last_name | email |gender | position | salary | origin_country |
|:---- |:------:| :-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|-----:|
| Tawnya  | Witheford    | twitheford0@seattletimes.com | Female | Technical Architect | 58286 | Russia
| Anna  | Witheford    | twitheford0@seattletimes.com | Female | Technical Architect | 58286 | Mexico
| Annie  | Witheford    | twitheford0@seattletimes.com | Female | Technical Architect | 58286 | China
```

Its showing the error as shown below :

---

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 14>()
12 # Assuming you have a DataFrame named 'employee_data' with columns like 'origin_country', 'employee_id'
13 # Replace 'employee_data' with your actual DataFrame
---> 14 selected_employee = employee_data[employee_data['origin_country'] == your_origin_country].iloc[0,:]

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_integer(self, key, axis)
1555         len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
1556         if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
-> 1557             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
1558
1559     # -------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

My employee_data is the dataframe. I wanted to select an employee from the dataframe with country name as 'China'. But I am getting the above error. Could anyone help me out in this ?

I have updated the code according to the below comments by some users :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Step 1: Select an Employee
# Replace 'your_origin_country' with the desired country
your_origin_country = 'Canada'

employee_data = df
employee_data
# Assuming you have a DataFrame named 'employee_data' with columns like 
'origin_country', 'employee_id'
# Replace 'employee_data' with your actual DataFrame
selected_employee = employee_data[employee_data['origin_country'] == your_origin_country].reset_index()
selected_employee.head(1)
```

But I am getting blank header with no data.

Comment: Post your dataframe and error traceback as text instead of [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Okay.............

Comment: I have changed the image to texts.

Comment: Does your dataframe have "China"/"Canada" in it? Check if it has any trailing or leading spaces etc. There might be some extra characters read which could be causing you the errors.

Comment: can you check if this returns anything?  `df[df['origin_country'].str.contains(your_origin_country)]`

Answer (score 0):

Filtering through `df[df[col] == var]` does not alter the indices of rows in `df.` It just returns all the rows where `df[col]==var` evaluates to `True`. So when use `.iloc[0,:]`, you are attempting to access a row by index which has been filtered out. That's why you get `IndexError`.

To solve this, you could use `.reset_index()` after filtering, which will reset the indexes where row position 0 is in bounds (if the DataFrame is not empty). More appropriately, you can use `head(1)`, which returns the first row of a DataFrame.

Comment: I have tried it. But I am getting no data. I have given the modified data above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are complicating this, if I understand your requirement right, this below code should get you the result

```
your_origin_country = "China"
df = df.query('origin_country == @your_origin_country')
```

Comment: I have tried this. But I am getting a blank table with no data just the header